# Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

[image: issue]

I am using `react-i18next`. Sometime on init function component facing React issue. Any idea what may causing it?

My config

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import resources from "./locales";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

const options = {
  debug: false,
  lng: "en",
  resources: resources,
  fallbacking: "en",
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init(options);

export default i18n;
```

My versions

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-i18next": "^11.7.2",
```

Comment: I ran into this issue, but with rendering table rows. The problem in my case was the array items were missing unique keys. React was not emitting that error/warning, which made it very difficult to find.

Answer (score 10):

stupid bug which was inited by myself. I was simple declaring before return dom component, like

```
const test = (props)=>{
  if(props.test){
     return <p>test</p>
  }
   const { t } = useTranslation("Test");//this must be on very top
  return <p>Main {t('test_variable')}</p>
}
```

I wish if react could be more clear in logging bugs

Answer (score 2):

you might try this configuration, it works with me perfectly

```
 import i18n from "i18next";
 import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";  
 import { initReactI18next, Trans } from "react-i18next";
 import lang from "assets/lang";

 i18n.use(LanguageDetector)
 .use(initReactI18next)
 .init({
// we init with resources
 resources: lang,
 fallbackLng: "en",
 debug: true,

// have a common namespace used around the full app
 ns: ["basic"],
 defaultNS: "basic",

keySeparator: false, // we use content as keys

interpolation: {
  escapeValue: false,
},
 });

window.document.body.dir = i18n.t("dir");

  export default i18n;

  const Tr = (props) => (
  <Trans i18nKey={props.tr} {...props}>
  {props.children}
 </Trans>
  );

  Tr.tr = (key, ...rest) => i18n.t(key, ...rest);

 export { Tr };
```

Comment: look`s cool, the main difference ive noticed i am using func hook ```useTranslation``` instead your example with component wrapping

Answer (score 1):

I've also had such a problem and finally I found that the main reason of this problem is using hooks in wrong place, you need to use your hook in parent component and not the child one. For example, you have a todo list and todo component, you have to use it in todo list and not in todo.

Comment: I think it's not always true. You have 100 component and 1 parent one. You need to use all hooks in first one?

Answer (score 1):

I too recently came across the same issue on my Next.js web-app. I simply fixed it by removing a **conditional statement** which I was using while **invoking a React hook**. It can come as a **hydration error** too if you check your Browser console: it might print a similar Warning ⚠️, like: Inconsistent order of Hooks execution.

Sample Snippet of my fix:

Earlier:

```js
const startDate = startDateValue && useDateHook(startDateValue)
```

Fix:

```js
const startDate = useDateHook(startDateValue || new Date())
```

I ensured invoking the (custom) hook always, rather than doing it conditionally.